# Parse.com Core Data: Exclude fields from being exposed to frontend based on roles

Tags: security, parse-platform

Is there any way to exclude fields from being exposed to the frontend in Parse Core Data? E.g. I have a `User` model that has the field `email`. Now I want to permit that other users can get certain information about the user but **not** the email address. Only admins should be permitted to fetch the email address from the backend. Is there any chance to realize this with Parse.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use ACL per field (at least to this day).

I believe the best approach for your problem is to create another class named `PublicUserProfile` (make it public read, no public write), make the `User` class private (set public read/write to false) and reference the public profile from the User class (and vice versa). That way you could expose only what you define as 'public'.

You could also make the `User` class private and use cloud code to expose only the data you want, but then you might lose some of Parse features (via its client code). Using this solution, your user profile doesn't 'span' on two classes (compared to my first suggestion). It will make, for example, editing user fields much simpler. It's a trade-off you'll have to make.

Comment: I found similar question ( https://parse.com/questions/hiding-email-addresses-from-user-payload ) on Parse.com